# If I expand my answer, should I notify the question asker?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

If I answer a question and the question asker comments on my answer and I edit it later to address their comment (add information etc.), should I notify the asker by writing a comment?

Comment: Side note: you may want to edit your question to be less about "should you" (which is really your personal call) and more about whether edit of answer somehow notifies asker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should I notify the asker by writing a comment?

The OP won't be automatically notified when you have edited/updated your answer.
You might ping them with a comment on the question post, if you notice they didn't care about their question with in a reasonable period of time (6-8 weeks<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note this is an internal joke, giving an *arbitrary* time scale for questions about any action done on posts within a certain time.</sub>